# Android app submit button not working on sending gps data to mysql server

Tags: java, android, mysql, gps

I'm trying to create a simple app that submits GPS data to a website MySql server but when I added the code for getting the GPS location the submit button stopped working

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText inputName;
String currentTimeDate;
TextView timeView, latView, lonView;
double longitude, latitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pushData);
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latView);
    lonView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lonView);

    timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeView);
    currentTimeDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    timeView.setText(currentTimeDate);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new InsertAsync().execute("http://androidemployeelog.eu/php-service/dbsave.php");
        }
    });


}

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        String lat = Double.toString(latitude);
        String lon = Double.toString(longitude);

        latView.setText(lat);
        lonView.setText(lon);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
};

class InsertAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    String name = inputName.getText().toString();
    String phoneTime = currentTimeDate.toString();
    String lat = Double.toString(latitude);
    String lon = Double.toString(longitude);
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String isSucess = "0";



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setTitle("Logging Information");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("phoneTime", phoneTime)
                .add("phoneLat", lat)
                .add("phoneLon", lon)
                .add("nameInput", name)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(params[0])
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String result = response.body().string();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            isSucess = jsonObject.getString("success");

            Log.d("isSuccess", isSucess);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        inputName.setText("");

        inputName.hasFocus();

        if (isSucess.equals("1")) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Submission successful", duration);
            toast.show();
        }
        if (isSucess.equals("0")) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Submission failed, please check your internet connection and try again", duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Submit button stopped working is a very bad description when you try to get gps location and do an upload. Come to the point!

Comment: Looks like you're using Marshmallow or higher versioned Android device. So, in your code you're checking for the access location permission and if the permission hasn't granted just returning from there. That's why it's not working. You should handle that request permission.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sorry the title was not on point, I was trying to keep it short